CORS Error when calling an API via Chrome Extension
my app is deployed on Vercel https://abc/api/something - it's an open endpoint to serve a specific request. I'm trying to call this API from my Chrome extension code. It works fine locally, but in production, it gives a CORS error.
Error:
Access to fetch at 'https://abc/api/something' from origin 'chrome-extension://pkomeokalhjlopcgnoefibpdabcdefg' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
const apiUrl = "https://abc/api/something";
const response = await fetch(apiUrl, {
  method: "POST",
  headers: {
    Accept: "application/json",
    "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
  },
  body: body,
});

I've tried everything I read online. Here's the OPTIONS method in my code:
export async function OPTIONS(request: Request) {
  const origin = request.headers.get('origin')
  return new NextResponse(null, {
    status: 204,
    headers: {
      'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': origin || '*',
      "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "GET,OPTIONS,PATCH,DELETE,POST,PUT",
      "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "*",
    },
  });
}

And here's the response headers I'm setting:
{
  status: 200,
  headers: {
    "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
    "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "GET,OPTIONS,PATCH,DELETE,POST,PUT",
    "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "*",
  },
}

I've also configured my Next.js config:
async headers() {
  return [
    {
      source: "/api/:path*",
      headers: [
        { key: "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", value: "true" },
        { key: "Access-Control-Allow-Origin", value: "*" },
        { key: "Access-Control-Allow-Methods", value: "GET,OPTIONS,PATCH,DELETE,POST,PUT" },
        { key: "Access-Control-Allow-Headers", value: "X-CSRF-Token, X-Requested-With, Accept, Accept-Version, Content-Length, Content-MD5, Content-Type, Date, X-Api-Version" },
      ],
    },
  ];
},
async rewrites() {
  return [
    {
      source: '/api/something',
      destination: 'https://abc/api/something',
    },
  ];
},

How do I fix this? Any help is appreciated.

"it gives a CORS error"... which is????

sorry about that: Error: Access to fetch at 'https://abc/api/something' from origin 'chrome-extension://pkomeokalhjlopcgnoefibpdabcdefg' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

Add the site to host_permissions in manifest.json.
